# Why does my C project compilation cannot find my structure?

Tags: c, struct, compilation

I had a project based on a single C file that I try to rearrange for further development in several .c and .h files.

My main is organised as follow:

```
// General includes

typedef struct 
{
} MyStruct;

#include "MyInclude.h"

// Rest of the code
```

My file "MyInclude.c" is organised as follow:

```
#include "MyInclude.h"

// Defines

// Functions that need to know MyStruct
```

There is something I don't understant about the compilation process of GCC. In fact, I got the error "MyStruct undeclared (first use in this function)" and I don't why as I put my include after the typedef declaration of my structure.

Does someone knows why it happens?

Comment: Shouldn't the structure be in the header file?

Comment: What is in MyInclude? Is `MyStruct` really empty?

Comment: Let me rephrase my previous comment: *Why* isn't the structure defined in the header file? If you have multiple source files that depend in the structure, they will not know about it, only the source file where it's defined will know about the structure.

Comment: I need to know MyStruct in all my .c files (in main.c and MyInclude.c) I thought it would be the same to define it in my main.c. I will need to implement other MyInclude.c files that will need it as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear.

The file "MyInclude.c" can access only to your H file.
While your struct is written in another C file.

You can solve it by:

1. Define the struct on the H file "MyInclude.h". It will work, but methodologically it's wrong.
2. Define setters and getters to access your struct

Cheers

Comment: There is nothing "methodologically wrong" about placing the `typedef` in header file, that's how it's usually done. Also, getters and setters are irrelevant for this question, as it seems to be about type declaration troubles, and not about variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Your file.h :

```
// file.h
#include <stdio.h> //Juste for printf

typedef struct s_data
{
char c;
} t_data;
```

Your file.c :

```
#include "file.h"

int main()
{
t_data data;

data.c = 'a';
printf("%c", data.c);
return (0);
}
```

Compil (if your file .c and .h are in the same directory):

```
gcc file.c -o my_app -I .
```